# How to easily Generate Synth Chords Sounds in Android?

Tags: android, chord, sound-synthesis

How to easily Generate Synth Chords Sounds in Android?
I wanna be able to generate dynamically an in game Music using 8bit.
Tried with *AudioTrack*, but did not get good results of nice sounds yet.

Any examples out there?

I have tried the following code without success:

```
public class BitLoose {
    private final int duration = 1; // seconds
    private final int sampleRate = 4200;
    private final int numSamples = duration * sampleRate;
    private final double sample[] = new double[numSamples];

    final AudioTrack audioTrack;

    public BitLoose() {
        audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT, numSamples,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
        audioTrack.play();
    }

    public void addTone(final int freqOfTone) {
        // fill out the array
        for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; ++i) {
            sample[i] = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / (sampleRate / freqOfTone));
        }

        // convert to 16 bit pcm sound array
        // assumes the sample buffer is normalised.
        final byte generatedSnd[] = new byte[numSamples];

        int idx = 0;
        for (final double dVal : sample) {
            // scale to maximum amplitude
            final short val = (short) ((((dVal * 255))) % 255);
            // in 16 bit wav PCM, first byte is the low order byte
            generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) (val);
        }
        audioTrack.write(generatedSnd, 0, sampleRate);
    }

    public void stop() {
        audioTrack.stop();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that bad sound is due to audio format: AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT uses unsigned samples, so a sine between 1 and -1 must be converted to 0-255 byte values, try this:

```
for (final double dVal : sample) {
    final short val = (short) ((dVal + 1) / 2 * 255) ;
    generatedSnd[idx++] = (byte) val;
}
```

Try also to change sample rate to 11025, because 4200 may be unsupported on some devices:

```
private final int sampleRate = 11025;
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from answer 1 you should use:
    sample[i] = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / (**(double)** sampleRate / freqOfTone)); 
instead of 
    sample[i] = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / (sampleRate / freqOfTone));